# Node.js exports from folder

Tags: node.js

I read the node.js tutorial and can not figure out the line `require('./app/routes')(app, {})` in server.js

Project structure is like:

```
-app
  -routes
    -index.js
    -note_routes.js
-server.js
```

index.js:

```
const noteRoutes = require('./note_routes')
module.exports = function(app, db){
    noteRoutes(app, db)
}
```

note_routes.js

```
module.exports = function(app, db) {
    app.post('/notes', (req, res) => {
      res.send('Hello')
    });
  };
```

How if we import a folder, node.js understands that it needs to import the index.js module not note_routes, if the export lines are the same

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How if we import a folder, node.js understands that it needs to import the index.js module not note_routes, if the export lines are the same

Because that's built into Node. If you are trying to require a directory, Node will look for specific files in that directory.

The details can be found [in the documentation](https://nodejs.org/api/modules.html#modules_all_together). An excerpt:

```
LOAD_INDEX(X)
1. If X/index.js is a file, load X/index.js as JavaScript text.  STOP
2. If X/index.json is a file, parse X/index.json to a JavaScript object. STOP
3. If X/index.node is a file, load X/index.node as binary addon.  STOP
```

Comment: Oh, did not see this part in the documentation.
Now I understand, thanks!